# Calling a function of an struct array (Problem with “undefined function”) Use of typedef should solve it?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, typedef

I wrote some simplifyed code to demonstrate the case. The goal is to call some funtions out of an struct array. In this implementation i get the following remark: "call to function 'unidentified function' not made in the presence of a prototype"

I guess that typedefs has to be used. I just dont get it working with typedefs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

struct FuctionCallList
{
  void (*const call_function)();
  bool activated;
};


void testPrint1(void);
void testPrint2(void);



struct FuctionCallList sFuctionCallList[] =                                  
{  //Function to call   Activ        
  {testPrint1,          false},
  {testPrint2,          true}
};

__uint16_t  sFuctionCallListSize = sizeof(sFuctionCallList) / sizeof(struct FuctionCallList);

void testPrint1()                                                                
{
 printf("Hello World function 1");
}

void testPrint2()                                                                
{
 printf("Hello World function 2");
}


int main()
{
  __uint8_t i;

  for(i = 0; i < sFuctionCallListSize; i++)
  {
    if(sFuctionCallList[i].activated == true) 
    {
      sFuctionCallList[i].call_function();                       // problematic call
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, this code works as expected. Though strictly speaking `void (*)()` is a different function pointer type than `void(*)(void)`. Maybe the problem is that you declared the prototypes correctly with `(void)` parameter, but the actual functions with obsolete style empty parameter list `()`.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you unsloppify the code? https://godbolt.org/z/FgjbKr

Comment: Thank you `void (*const call_function)(void);` fixed it. I guess it depends strongly on the compiler and its settings. To have a full answer to the question (also for others), it might be interesting how the example code would look like with typdefs used in the correct way.